# How to Add dynamic where clause in codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter and trying to make a dynamic query,
right now my query looks like

```
$query = $this->db->select('name')->get('user');
$result_array = $query->result_array();
```

My question is, how to add a dynamic where clause depending upon variable value?
so the code will look like

```
$query = $this->db->select('name')->get('user');
if(isset($name))
{
  //add where clause here, to select specific name
}
$result_array = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call **`where()`** in the if statement, before calling **`get()`**.

```
$this->db->select('name');

if(isset($name))
{
    //add where clause here, to select specific name
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
}

$query = $this->db->get('user');    
$result_array = $query->result_array();
```

**Documentation:**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by one line query. If you're referring to the fact that the methods are not chained, yes it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('name');
$name = $this->input->post('name');
if(isset($name) &&  $name  != '' && !empty($name))
{

    $this->db->where('name',$name );
}

$query = $this->db->get('user');    
$result_array = $query->result_array();
```

go though onece active record in codeigniter

https://www.codeigniter.com/user-guide/database/active_record.html