# CodeIgniter - SQL sentence IF then WHERE?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, if-statement, where-clause

Currently I am capable of doing WHERE sentences in CodeIgniter as follows:

```
$builder = $db->table('mytable');
$builder->select(*);
$builder->where('age >='.$params['some-param']);
```

What I need to do, is a WHERE statement that only applies if an IF statement is true. Something like:

```
(IF gender = 'Male', apply these rows the following where) $builder->where('age >='.$params['some-param']);
(IF gender = 'Female', apply these other rows, this where and not the first one) $builder->where('age >='.$params['some-other-param']);
```

Also note that ['some-param'] and ['some-other-param'] won't always exist. I get that it can be achieved with OR sentence but if ['some-other-param'] is not setted, then the query would be something like:

```
$builder->where("age >=".$params['some-param']." AND gender = 'Male'");
```

And that would not include any row with gender = 'Female', which I also need.

I have no clue of how to achieve this. Any orientation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
-- Both age filters are set
select *
from my_table
where (
    (gender = 'Male' and age >= 20)
    or 
    (gender = 'Female' and age >= 30)
)

-- Only Male filter is set
select *
from my_table
where (
    (gender = 'Male' and age >= 20)
    or 
    gender = 'Female'
)

-- Only Female filter is set
select *
from my_table
where (
    (gender = 'Female' and age >= 20)
    or 
    gender = 'Male'
)
```

Comment: It would work but those filters won't always exist. So, if there's no 'Female' age filter, then it would be something like $builder->where(gender = 'Male' and age >= 20 ). And that would not include any Female. What I need is to get both male and female but to include those filters only if the user sets them.

Comment: Then can't you just use `if .. then .. else ..` statement to check if the parameters are set and based on that create the query? It should be possible, no? I think here is something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462064/how-to-add-dynamic-where-clause-in-codeigniter-query

Comment: That's actually what I'm currently doing. My point is, I need all data to be filtered. But if you set an optional parameter of female age or male age, query should only filter female, male or both (depending on the case) by the input age or ages. But if, for example user enters ONLY male age, then a normal where query would be where(" gender = 'Male' AND age >= ."$param['male-age-filter']), wouldn't that only select Male rows? In that case I need only Male to be filtered but also include Females.

Comment: So if both are parameters are set then `WHERE` clause would look like my example above. In case only male age filter is set then it would be `WHERE (gender = 'Male' and age >= 20) OR gender = 'Female'`. And if only female filter is set then it would be `WHERE (gender = 'Female' and age >= 20) OR gender = 'Male'`

Comment: That sounds like it. I will try it.